# My Driver Class Compiles But Does Not Return Expected Value

Tags: java, stack

Alright, so when the program runs there are no errors, but the expected  output is not returned. The program just reprints the string instead of converting it. Included here is the code for the PostfixtoInfix2 class. The method relies on the other methods working properly. I cannot identify which method run incorrectly. Any ideas, better coding conventions, or solutions are welcomed.

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class PostfixtoInfix2 
  /*
 * This class takes an expression in Infix and translates it to Prefix.
 * */

{
  public String expression;
  public Stack <Character> s= new Stack();


  public String PostfixtoInfix(String e)
  {expression = e;
    String output ="";
    for(int i=0; i < expression.length(); i++)
      {char currentChar = expression.charAt(i);
         if(isOperator(currentChar))
              {while(!s.empty() && s.peek() != '(' && hasHigherPrecedence(s.peek(), currentChar))
                        {output += s.peek();
                         s.pop();
              }
                  s.push(currentChar);
              }
          else if(isOperand(currentChar))
          {output += currentChar;
          }
          else if(currentChar == '(')
          {s.push(currentChar);
          }
          else if(currentChar == ')')
          {while(!s.empty() && s.peek() != ')')
            {output += s.peek();
             s.pop();
             }
          }
          while(!s.empty())
          {output += s.peek();
            s.pop();
          }
    } return output;
  }

public boolean isOperator(char c)
{
if(c =='+' || c=='-' || c=='/' || c=='*' || c== '^')
  return true;
return false;
}

 public boolean isOperand( char c)
 {if(c>='0' && c<='9') return true;
   if(c>= 'a' && c<= 'z') return true;
   if(c>= 'A' && c<= 'Z') return true;
   return false;
 }

 public int getOperatorWeight(char operator)
 {int weight = -1;
   switch (operator)
   {case '+':
     case'-':
     weight =1;
     break;

     case '*':
     case '/':
       weight = 2;
       break;

     case '^':
       weight =3;
   }
   return weight;
 }

 public boolean hasHigherPrecedence(char operator1, char operator2)
 {
 int op1 = getOperatorWeight(operator1);
 int op2 = getOperatorWeight(operator2);
 if(op1==op2)
 {if(isRightAssociative(operator1))return false;
   else return true;
 }
 return op1> op2 ? true : false;
 }

 public boolean isRightAssociative(char op)
 {
 if(op == '^') return true;
 return false;
 } 
}

public class PostfixDemo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  { PostfixtoInfix2 j = new PostfixtoInfix2();
    System.out.print(j.PostfixtoInfix("3218+-"));
  }
}
```

Comment: What "output" are you expecting? This program does not print anything to either Standard Error or Standard Out

Comment: In the PostfixtoInfix method in the second to last line it should return the String "output" variable.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to produce output. Where do you expect the output to come from?

Comment: it might return something, but you're not printing the return...

Comment: System.out.println(j.PostfixtoInfix(...);

Comment: Thank You for the swift comments, I have changed the code to reflect your corrections, but the expected output is still not being returned.

Comment: That is a very .... *unique* .... indentation and bracing style. You might want to follow a more common style, e.g. [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces). There are others, but I've only ever seen code directly after a start-brace in single-line occurrences, i.e. the end-brace is also on that same line, but even that is not common. And never code after end-brace, except `else`.

Comment: It took me a while to even recognize this was Java.  Can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Also things like `if (boolean) { return false; } else { return true; }` make my head spin. Why not `return !boolean`? This includes the ternary simplification `return boolean ? true : false`